# Compiler warnings with gtm-oauth, how do I get rid of them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

Here's a picture of the code and the corresponding warnings in the GTMOAuthAuthentication.h file from Google's gtm-oauth Cocoa library.

[image]

What exactly is causing these warnings? How do I fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project has been updated. Be sure to write to the project's mailing list with issues about the library.